# How to add an inline HTML column to a suitescript sublist?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have a sublist like that below that I want to be able to add images/custom HTML into one particular column. How can this be done in SuiteScript 2.0? Is there a workaround by any chance?

```
var sublist = form.addSublist({
    id: 'sublist',
    type: ui.SublistType.LIST,
    label: 'User Details',
});
var currAddSublist = sublist.addField({
    id: 'custpage_testcol3',
    label: 'User Type',
    // Does not allow me to set this as inline HTML
    type: ui.FieldType.INLINEHTML
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I was actually able to accomplish what was required by using a TEXT field and including the image tags within. I had thought that an INLINEHTML field would be needed.

Comment: You can also do it using TEXTAREA : netsuite prohibit using INLINEHTML in sublist (it is mentioned in the Help) : but the way they show TEXT or TEXTAREA in a lists of types LIST and STATICLIST (or by setting the display type of the field itself) make it possible to use tags in those (there is no Tag filtering).

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit of a hacky solution but you can set the client script for a suitelet via serverWidgetForm.clientScriptFileId. In the client script it is possible to use jQuery to manipulate the suitelet to how you want it. I believe if you add a field to the suitelet, the id will also be the id in its corresponding html element.